# I am trying to make a div slide in on load and my previous solution is no longer working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I posted this yesterday, and the code was working but today it is not. I just can't seem to get my javascript to fire off and show the animation of the div? any ideas?

I have the js in a seperate file and fire it from the body with a script tag.

```js
function slideOnLoad(){
  document.getElementById("right-scroll-slide").style.top="10px";
}
slideOnLoad();
```

```css
#right-scroll-slide{
  -webkit-transition:all 1s;
  -ms-transition:all 1s;
  -moz-transition:all 1s;
  -o-transition:all 1s;
    position:absolute;
  top:-100px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-scroll-content" id="right-scroll-slide">aaaa</div>
```

I would have included a jsfiddle, but it doesn't seem to be loading right now.

Comment: No need for JSFiddle. I've converted your code into a code snippet.

Comment: Would you be open to a JQuery solution?

Comment: I would, but I'm not very good with it and would need to be able to recycle it for multiple animation solutions  @JamesDonnelly thanks man!

Comment: looks like there is a missing semi-colon after -o-transition:all 1s

Comment: @WayneC Oops, I posted this yesterday and got that error, I copied the code from my previously question, I have the semi-colon in my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use animate and change `top` to `margin-top` in the css

**Demo**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kwzqvq

**Jquery**

```
 function slideOnLoad(){
      $('#right-scroll-slide').animate({'margin-top':'0px'},0) 
    }
    slideOnLoad();
```

**Css**

```
 #right-scroll-slide{
      -webkit-transition:all 1s;
      -ms-transition:all 1s;
      -moz-transition:all 1s;
      -o-transition:all 1s;
        position:absolute;
      margin-top:-100px;
      background:red;
    }
```

Comment: Place the juery code at the end of your HTML page or put the code in a document ready function ($( document ).ready(function() {  ..code..   });)

Comment: Just put it in bottom script tag and now it works, let me try putting it in a document read function, one sec EDIT: it wors in the document ready function! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function slideOnLoad(){
  document.getElementById("right-scroll-slide").style.top="0px";
}
slideOnLoad();
```

```css
#right-scroll-slide{
  -webkit-transition:all 1s;
  -ms-transition:all 1s;
  -moz-transition:all 1s;
  -o-transition:all 1s;
    position:absolute;
  top:-100px;
  background:red;
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div class="right-scroll-content" id="right-scroll-slide">aaaa</div>
```